# How do I connect Counterparty B to C and vice versa without changing the arragement

Tags: graphviz, dot, edges

How do I connect counterparty B to D and vice versa without changing the arrangement setup.

Here are the codes

```
digraph graphname {
        A [label="Counterparty A" color=Blue, fontcolor=Red, fontsize=24, shape=box]      // node T
        B [label="Counterparty B" color=Blue, fontcolor=Red, fontsize=24, shape=box]  // node P
        C [label="Counterparty C"  color=Blue,fontcolor=Red,fontsize=24,shape=box]
        D [label="Counterparty D" color=Blue, fontcolor=Red, fontsize=24, shape=box]
        A->{B,C}->{D}[fontcolor =darkgreen,dir="both"]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Do you mean _B to C_? B and D are already connected.

Answer (score 0):

Your subject line says *B to C* but in the text you say *B to D*, hence the confusion.

`graphviz` needs another instruction telling it to keep `B` and `C` on the same rank, see the commented code below.

```
digraph graphname 
{
        // introduced to increase the distance between B and C:
        nodesep = .5;

        A [label="Counterparty A" color=Blue, fontcolor=Red, fontsize=24, shape=box]      // node T
        B [label="Counterparty B" color=Blue, fontcolor=Red, fontsize=24, shape=box]  // node P
        C [label="Counterparty C"  color=Blue,fontcolor=Red,fontsize=24,shape=box]
        D [label="Counterparty D" color=Blue, fontcolor=Red, fontsize=24, shape=box]
        A->{B,C}->{D}[fontcolor =darkgreen,dir="both"]

        // we make sure that the two nodes B and C stay side by side,
        // and connect them:
        { rank = same; B -> C[ dir = both ] }     
}
```

yields

[image]